# Parsing logs in OTEL (opentelemetery) agent

Tags: parsing, otel

Otel agent is running as daemonset in kubernetes. I want to parse below logs and extract fields like method, agent, host etc:

2023-04-23T12:09:51.340741265Z stdout F 10.110.245.37 - - [23/Apr/2023:12:09:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 615 "-" "Wget" "-"
2023-04-23T12:09:52.345193051Z stdout F 10.110.245.37 - - [23/Apr/2023:12:09:52 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 615 "-" "Wget" "-"

Below is my Otel agent configuration implemented as configmap: Below is the only change I did in configuration.

```
  receivers:
  filelog:
    include: [/var/log/pods/*_php-apache*_*/*/*.log] 
    start_at: beginning
    operators:
      - type: regex_parser
        regex: '^(?P<time>[^ ]+) (?P<stream>stdout|stderr) (?P<logtag>[^ ]*) (?P<host>[^ ]*)'
        output: extract_metadata_filepath
        timestamp:
          layout: '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ'
          parse_from: attributes.time

       - type: regex_parser
         id: extract_metadata_filepath
         regex: '^(?P<host>[^ ]*)'
         parse_from: body
       - type: move
         from: attributes.host
         to: resource["custom.my_field"]
```

Ideally I should get field custom_my_field  containing hosts. But there is no such field. What do I need to change in OTLP agent to extract fields like method, agent, hosts, code etc